# using openNN in visual studio (unresolved external symbol)

Tags: c++, visual-studio

I am looking to use the C++ neural network library "OpenNN". 
http://www.opennn.net/

I am relatively new to C++ project management and I believe my issue is caused by this.

I have cloned the openNN repo.

I copied the relevant folders form the repo across in to the folder that i created to contain all OpenNN project i plan to make.

I then made a c++ console application in visual studio, in this folder that i am using for testing.

so dir structure is :

OpenNN (where i plan to keep all openNN projects)
 
---`eigen`
 
---`opennn`
 
---`tinyxml2`
 
---`OpenNNTest` (my test project folder)

I have done some testing with the Vector and Matrix classes that are part of OpenNN and that all worked fine.

The below code however returns the following two external symbol errors:

```
Error   LNK2019 unresolved external symbol "public: __thiscall OpenNN::NeuralNetwork::NeuralNetwork(class OpenNN::Vector<unsigned int> const &)" (??0NeuralNetwork@OpenNN@@QAE@ABV?$Vector@I@1@@Z) referenced in function "void __cdecl NNTest(void)" (?NNTest@@YAXXZ)  OpenNNTest  D:\Projects\OpenNN\OpenNNTest\OpenNNTest\OpenNNTest.obj 1   

Error   LNK2019 unresolved external symbol "public: virtual __thiscall
OpenNN::NeuralNetwork::~NeuralNetwork(void)" (??1NeuralNetwork@OpenNN@@UAE@XZ) referenced in function "void __cdecl NNTest(void)" (?NNTest@@YAXXZ)  OpenNNTest  D:\Projects\OpenNN\OpenNNTest\OpenNNTest\OpenNNTest.obj 1
```

interestingly, if I change:

```
OpenNN::NeuralNetwork nn(architecture);
```

to

```
OpenNN::NeuralNetwork nn();
```

No issues, as if it finds the default constructor but not the overloaded one?

The code I am using is as follows:

```
#include "stdafx.h"

#include "../../opennn/opennn.h"
using namespace OpenNN;

using std::cout;
using std::endl;

void NNTest()
{
    OpenNN::Vector<unsigned> architecture(5);
    architecture[0] = 2;
    architecture[1] = 2;
    architecture[2] = 4;
    architecture[3] = 3;
    architecture[4] = 1;

    OpenNN::NeuralNetwork nn(architecture);

    //Vector<double> inputs(2);
    //inputs[0] = 0.5;
    //inputs[1] = 0.1;

    //Vector<double> outputs = nn.calculate_outputs(inputs);

    //cout << outputs << endl;

    //nn.save("neural_network.xml");


}

int main()
{
    NNTest();

    getchar();

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to change the type unsigned to size_t:

```
OpenNN::Vector<size_t> architecture(5);
architecture[0] = 2;
architecture[1] = 2;
architecture[2] = 4;
architecture[3] = 3;
architecture[4] = 1;

OpenNN::NeuralNetwork nn(architecture);
```

I hope that helps.